# Doing multiple gsub in a rails 3 app on email body template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, templates, gsub

I have an email template where the user can enter text like this:

`Hello {first_name}, how are you?`

and when the email actually gets sent it replaces the placeholder text {first_name} with the actual value.

There will be several of these placeholders, though, and I wasn't sure that gsub is meant to be used like this.

`body = @email.body.gsub("{first_name}", @person.first_name)gsub("{last_name}", @person.last_name).gsub("",...).gsub("",...).gsub("",...).etc...`

Is there a cleaner solution to achieving this functionality?  Also, if anyone's done something similar to this, did they find that they eventually hit a point where using multiple gsubs on a few paragraphs for hundreds of emails was just too slow?

EDIT

I ran some tests comparing multiple gsubs vs using regex and it came out that the regex was usually 3x FASTER than using multiple gsubs.  However, I think the regex code is a littler harder to read as-is, so I'm going to have to clean it up a bit but it does indeed seem that using regex is significantly faster than multiple gsubs.  Since my use case will involve multiple substitutions for a large number of documents, the faster solution is better for me, even though I'll have to add a little more documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put in regular expressions all strings you want to catch and in the hash you put the replacement of all catches:

```
"123456789".gsub /(123|456)/, "123" => "ABC",
                              "456" => "DEF"
```

This code only works for ruby 1.9.

If you can use a template library like erb or haml, they are the proper tool for this kind of task.

Comment: Interesting; is this going to be more efficient than doing multiple gsubs? I'm thinking that from a readability standpoint, multiple gsubs would be more understandable to someone else looking at my code. Are there any other benefits to using the regex approach vs the multiple gsubs?

Comment: I found this solution to be much faster than multiple gsubs. Wish it were "cleaner" to read, but the speed benefits out weigh writing some documentation for other developers. Thanks!